# HTML/Javascript page transition

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web, transition

I've been browsing Awwwards and i saw websites that has a custom page transition specifically this one https://phoenix.cool/ and I've been wondering how do they do that smooth transition to other page. If you have any source on page transitions that would be highly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: You can achieve those transition also by using https://barba.js.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Handling URL change**

Usually you make use of [browser's history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), which means that you don't really navigate away fto another page, just update the url in the browser, f.e:

```
history.pushState({ foo: "bar" }, "Next page", "secondPage.html");
```

That allows providing seemingless experience. Note, that providing *secondPage.html* does not load any html. Everything but url change has to be handled manually by developer.

**Animation itself**

As you have to handle it manually, you can make it whatever you want. You can find neat examples on codrops (f.e. https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/07/a-collection-of-page-transitions/).
You have to attach animation to `window.onpopstate` event. Explanation in the very same MDN article.

There's link to good example at the bottom of the article where you can see example implementation.

*Edit:* **Ready made solution:**
I came across barba.js accidentally today and it seems to be precisely what you could be looking for. Check it out: http://barbajs.org

Comment: Thank you for that, really provided me some insights. another question, how to handle changes in html? do I need to use ajax?

Comment: well, that's totally dependant on what you want to do. If you have two pages; 'show' and 'hide' for example, then on popstate event you need apply visual changes based on if is the current state shown or hidden. Check out the demo http://html5doctor.com/demos/history/ and the article itself on html5doctor. The explain it pretty good. But to give you an answer: you don't need to use ajax, but that's what you usually do to get a new data. Other strategy (definetely not reccomended) is one from the demo: load everything and just toggle content.